# Masonry and Bootstrap Grid Item Height Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, height, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have a bootstrap grid with 12 items.

The item in grid position 5 has a considerable height difference to the rest of the grid.

Masonry strangely alters the position of this particular item to grid position 7, where it should simply remain in it's original position.

Is there anyway to stop masonry doing this? Can anyone offer a solution.

Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <!-- Below is just repeated by 12, the 5th item has a larger image height -->
    <div class="grid-item-content">
      <a href="#">
        <div>
          <img src="image.png" alt="masonry_image">
        </div>      
        <div class="bottom">
          <div>Test</div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true
});
```

EDIT:

I've taken the time to create this jsfiddle to show the problem described.

https://jsfiddle.net/cwiggo/uecLr08g/

Comment: Really need to see the code or an MCVE

Comment: `grid-item-content` and the other `grid` class aren't standard Bootstrap grid. Normally I've seen the `col-*` used for Masonry items

Comment: @ZimSystem I know they are not standard bootstrap grid classes. But I need a class or id to include when triggering the masonry script as you can see in the JS snippet i've provided.

Comment: You need to post an actual working example that demonstrates the problem you describe.

Comment: @vanburen i've added a link to a jsfiddle in the question above

Comment: This is the inherent nature of Masonry: wherever the most vertical space exists is where the next column should be placed in the grid. Column six is where it should be according to how Masonry functions. See [Issue #331](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/331) and also [Macy.js](https://github.com/bigbitecreative/macy.js) as an alternative since you can declare the `true` order of your columns with this library.